# Download CSV of dates of the imageCollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to download a CSV file containing the acquisition date of each Sentinel-2 image in a featureCollection. I filtered the following featureCollection:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');

var s2L2A_rawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 100)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', ['30SYJ']))
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

print('Sentinel-2 L2A raw data', s2L2A_rawData);
```

How can I download a CSV with the date of each image to work the data locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way is:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');

var s2L2A_rawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 100)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', ['30SYJ']))
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  //.filterBounds(geometry);

print('Sentinel-2 L2A raw data', s2L2A_rawData);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:s2L2A_rawData,
  folder: 'S2SR_test_dates',
  description:'images',
  selectors:['system:index'],
  fileFormat: 'csv'
})
```

you can change the property "system:index to "system":time_end"

Comment: Brilliant!  This is the most direct way to do it.  The `selectors` argument is very useful.

Comment: you can also add other properties, something like  `selectors:['system:index','CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','VEGETATION_PERCENTAGE'])` . Enjoy it ;) .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which extracts the 'sysem:time_end' property using `aggregate_array`, converts the list into a FeatureCollection and downloads it to Google Drive using `Export.table.toDrive`:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-01-01');
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');

var s2L2A_rawData = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 100)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', ['30SYJ']))
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

print('Sentinel-2 L2A raw data: ', s2L2A_rawData);

var property = 'system:time_end';
var dates = s2L2A_rawData.aggregate_array(property);

print('Sentinel-2 time serie dates: ', dates);

var dates_featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(dates
                                .map(function(element){
                                return ee.Feature(null,{property:element})}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: dates_featureCollection,
  folder: 'Test_Folder',
  description:'dates',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Alternatively you can copy the values from `dates` list in GeoJSON format and paste it into your own text document, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Note that dates are stored in Unix Time.